# How do I update a subdocument with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I'm trying to update a subdocument using mongoose. The document that the subdocument exists on is structured like so :

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true,
        required: true,
        match: [/.+@.+\..+/, "Please enter a valid email."]
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    characters: [characterSchema]
})
```

The actual subdocument looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const CharacterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    playerName: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    playerLevel: Number,
    highestSlot: Number,
    numberOfSlots: [{
        id: Number,
        slots: Number
    }]
})

module.exports = CharacterSchema
```

I've been trying to update the subdocument like so:

```
updateCharacter: async function (req, res) {
        try {
            const user = await db.Users.findOneAndUpdate(
                { _id: req.user._id, "characters.name": req.params.characterName },
                { $set: { "characters.$": req.body } }
            )
            res.json(user)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```

I get back a successful response but nothing happens to the subdocument and I have no idea what I need to change.

Comment: Rather than `"characters.name"`, do you want `"characters.playerName"`?

Comment: That was exactly it. Thanks for catching the typo!